# How to get a text element to align to the top of its container

Tags: css, layout, scale, typography

I'm working on CSS layout for a game that will have either images or letters alternately appear in the top, right, bottom, or left of the screen. I have a layout that is working as intended with images. The space between the images and the edge of the viewport should be constant:

```css
html {
  height: 100%; }

body {
  font: 100% "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%; }

#targetcontainer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%; }

.target {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-size: 20vw; }

.top img, .bottom img {
  max-width: 25%; }

.top img, .top span {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0; }

.bottom img {
  vertical-align: bottom; }

.left img, .right img {
  max-width: 50%; }

.top {
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center; }

.right {
  right: 0%;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  /* IE */
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%); }

.bottom {
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center; }

.left {
  left: 0%;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  /* IE */
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%); }
```

```html
<body>
        <div id="targetcontainer">
          <div class="target top">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://placem.at/things?w=100" />
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="target right">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://placem.at/things?w=100" />
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="target bottom">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://placem.at/things?w=100" />
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="target left">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://placem.at/things?w=100" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

However, when I replace the top image with a letter, I can't figure out how to get the letter to vertically align to the top of its container - it is aligning to the middle despite the `vertical-align: top;`. When scaling the browser width, you can see the letter "A" have a changing distance from the top of the viewport (in Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94, Mac OS 10.11.3).

```css
html {
      height: 100%; }

    body {
      font: 100% "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #333;
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 1em;
      overflow: auto;
      height: 100%; }

    #targetcontainer {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 100%; }

    .target {
      position: absolute;
      font-size: 4rem;
      font-size: 20vw; }

    .top img, .bottom img {
      max-width: 25%; }

    .top img, .top span {
      vertical-align: top;
      margin: 0; }

    .bottom img {
      vertical-align: bottom; }

    .left img, .right img {
      max-width: 50%; }

    .top {
      top: 0%;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center; }

    .right {
      right: 0%;
      width: 50%;
      text-align: right;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
      /* IE */
      -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
      /* Firefox */
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      /* Safari and Chrome */
      -o-transform: translateY(-50%); }

    .bottom {
      bottom: 0%;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center; }

    .left {
      left: 0%;
      width: 50%;
      text-align: left;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
      /* IE */
      -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
      /* Firefox */
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      /* Safari and Chrome */
      -o-transform: translateY(-50%); }
```

```html
<body>
            <div id="targetcontainer">
              <div class="target top">
                <a href="#">
                  <span class="letter">A</span>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="target right">
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="https://placem.at/things?w=100" />
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="target bottom">
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="https://placem.at/things?w=100" />
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="target left">
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="https://placem.at/things?w=100" />
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
        </body>
```

When using a letter as in the second snippet, how can I get it to maintain a constant distance from the top of the viewport while keeping the scaling of the font size based on browser width?

Here's a screenshot illustrating the issue:
[image: screenshot illustrating the desired vertical spacing]

Comment: Can't reproduce the bug.

Comment: It is top-aligned, but most fonts have some space above their letters, I believe that is your problem

Comment: @tschaefermedia I updated with a screenshot to clarify the issue

Comment: The space above is to leave room to accommodate letters such as Å. You can decrease the `line-height` for the element as a workaround; the amount depends on the font though.

Comment: So is there a workaround to achieve what I'm trying to do? I'm not going to use any letters with accents or anything over them for this game.

Comment: You can use line-height, as mentioned already. You can also use negative margin-top or translateY to nudge the element up. If you move it by a relative value, such as em, then you can hopefully arrive at a value that works regardless of the font size.